# MySQL And .net ConsoleApplication

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, console-application

What I did

I wanted to make a basic query in a Console Application (.NET)
When I do this in ASP.net on a aspx page. it works just fine. (100% same code, same 2 includes)

Any thoughts?

1. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net, Included both mysql.data, and mysql.web
2. added code below
3. It Crashes on Connection.Open();

Same Code works just fine in a asp.net aspx page.

Code:

```
string connstring = "";
string dataBase = "RollerCoaster";
string dataSource = "108.60.212.33";
string userID = "Mark";
string password = "------";
connstring = "Data source=" + dataSource + ";Database=" + dataBase + ";Port = 3307" + ";UserID= " + userID + ";Password=" + password;

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select id from reportedcoaster", connection);
command.Connection.Open();
```

-> Crash "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call"

Comment: Asp.net and console apps runs on same machine?

Comment: Yes. Both running in Debug Mode. The Database it self is on a server in another state. In Fact I tired useing another aspx page and had it run the code from the console app. (i put it in a class) added the console app by ref. and it runs just fine. it just doesnt run fine when its run directly by the console

Comment: Tested at Work, and its just fine on my work computer Same Version of Visual studio. Both brand new projects exact same code. Worked on the console here. But Why would it give me that error at home. Ill send home the project i have here at work and see if it has something to do with vs at home. But appears to be something wrong with my vs or my computer stopping it and casuing error. HMMM Gota be somthing on my computer causing it to error then....